# JavaScript: formatting input method gives wrong values

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm programming a method in JavaScript/JQuery which converts the value an user enters in an inputbox. The meaning is to make this input regional aware.
The functionality contains removing zeros at the beginning, placing thousand seperators and a decimal separator.

In this use case is the **,** symbol a thousand separator and the **.** dot the decimal separator

For example following input gets converted in following output.

- 12300 => 12,300.00
- 100 => 100.00
- 1023.456 => 1,023.456

Now There is still a problem with numbers, less than 100.
For example following input is malformed:

- 1 => 1,.00
- 2.05 => .05
- 20 => 20,.00
- 25.65 => .65

When I don't enter a decimal value in the input box, I get an unneeded thousand separator. When I enter a decimal value, I lose my content before the decimal separator.

The code:

```
$("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").change(function(){
                        var amount = $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").val();
                        amount = removeZeros(amount);
                        var nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
                        if(nonFractions == null) {
                            nonFractions = [];
                            nonFractions.push(amount);
                        }

                        var splittedValues = amount.split(/[,.]/);
                        amount = "";

                        if(splittedValues.length == 1) {
                            amount += splittedValues[0];
                            nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
                            var firstIndex = amount.length % 3;
                            if(firstIndex != 0) {
                            var firstNumbers = amount.substr(0, firstIndex);
                            amount = amount.substr(firstIndex);
                            nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);

                            if(nonFractions == null) {
                                nonFractions = [];
                                nonFractions.push(amount);
                            }

                            amount = "";

                            amount += firstNumbers;
                            amount += thousandSeparator;
                            } else {
                                amount = "";
                            }



                            for(var i=0 ; i < nonFractions.length ; i++) {
                                amount += nonFractions[i];

                                if(i < (nonFractions.length - 1) && nonFractions.length != 1){
                                    amount += thousandSeparator;
                                }
                            }

                            amount += decimalSeparator;
                            amount += "00";
                        } else {
                            for(var i=0 ; i < splittedValues.length - 1 ; i++) {
                                amount += splittedValues[i];
                            }

                            nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
                            var firstIndex = amount.length % 3;
                            if(firstIndex == 0) {
                                nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
                            }

                            if(firstIndex >= 1 && nonFractions != null) {
                                var firstNumbers = amount.substr(0, firstIndex);
                                amount = amount.substr(firstIndex);
                                nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);

                                if(nonFractions != null) {
                                    amount = "";
                                    amount += firstNumbers;
                                    amount += thousandSeparator;
                                } else {
                                    nonFractions = [];
                                    nonFractions.push(amount);
                                }
                            } else {

                                amount = "";
                            }


                            for(var i=0 ; i < nonFractions.length ; i++) {
                                amount += nonFractions[i];

                                if(i < (nonFractions.length - 1) && nonFractions.length != 1){
                                    amount += thousandSeparator;
                                }
                            }

                            amount += decimalSeparator;
                            amount += splittedValues[splittedValues.length -1];
                        }

        $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").val(amount);
      });
    });

function removeZeros(amount) {
            while (amount.charAt(0) === '0') {
                amount = amount.substr(1);
           }

           if(amount.length == 0){
            amount = "0";
           }
            return amount;
        }
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Are we missing some code? I don't see the definition for `removeZeros`

Comment: This code works in any case, but I'll add it.

Comment: Also, `thousandSeparator` please. so that we can run your code and modify it

Comment: That's a session variable, which gets injected in the jsp where I call the script, just replace the parameter by ",".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > What is going wrong?

I'd say almost everything. You have very unclear, messy code, I hardly following your logic, but you have several critical logic mistakes in code, for example:

**1**

1 is converted to 1,.00 because:

```
var splittedValues = amount.split(/[,.]/);
```

creates array with single element ['1']

```
var firstIndex = amount.length % 3;
```

1%3 == 1, so you're going into if condition, where `amount += thousandSeparator;` appends thousand separator, but you should add separator only if you have something after that

**2**

2.05 is wrong, because it goes into this branch:

```
var firstNumbers = amount.substr(0, firstIndex); // stores '2' into firstNumbers
amount = amount.substr(firstIndex); // sets amount to empty string
```

later, nonFractions is null:

```
nonFractions = [];
nonFractions.push(amount);
```

but firstNumbers is not used at all, ie its value is lost

**3**

also, you have:

```
    nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
    var firstIndex = amount.length % 3;
    if (firstIndex == 0) {
        nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
    }
```

what is the sense of nonFractions re-init?

probably there are more errors and edge cases where this code fails, I suggest you to use library (like in other answers) or if you want to have your own code, here is simple version you can use:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").change(function() {
        var val = parseFloat(('0' + $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").val()).replace(/,/g, '')); // convert original text value into float
        val = ('' + (Math.round(val * 100.0) / 100.0)).split('.', 2);
        if (val.length < 2) val[1] = '00'; // handle fractional part
        else while (val[1].length < 2) val[1] += '0';
        var t = 0;
        while ((val[0].length - t) > 3) { // append thousand separators
            val[0] = val[0].substr(0, val[0].length - t - 3) + ',' + val[0].substr(val[0].length - t - 3);
            t += 4;
        }
        $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").val(val[0] + '.' + val[1]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="queryInstructedAmountFrom">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)?

```
<input type="text" id="money" />
```

and just invoke the plugin:

```
$('#money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PY7ihpS3Amtzeya9c6KN?p=preview

Comment: That's not a solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below code updated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").change(function() {
        var amount = $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").val();
        amount = removeZeros(amount);
        
        // format amount using 'ThousandFormattedValue' function
        amount = ThousandFormattedValue(amount);

        $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").val(amount);
    });

});

function removeZeros(amount) {
    while (amount.charAt(0) === '0') {
        amount = amount.substr(1);
    }

    if (amount.length == 0) {
        amount = "0";
    }
    return amount;
}

function ThousandFormattedValue(iValue) {
    // declaring variables and initializing the values
    var numberArray, integerPart, reversedInteger, IntegerConstruction = "",
        lengthOfInteger, iStart = 0;

    // splitting number at decimal point by converting the number to string
    numberArray = iValue.toString().split(".");

    // get the integer part
    integerPart = numberArray[0];

    // get the length of the number
    lengthOfInteger = integerPart.length;

    // if no decimal part is present then add 00 after decimal point
    if (numberArray[1] === undefined) {
        numberArray.push("00");
    }


    /* split the integer part of number to individual digits and reverse the number
        ["4" , "3" , "2" , "1"] - after split
        ["1" , "2" , "3" , "4"] - after reverse
        "1234" - after join     
    */
    reversedInteger = integerPart.split("").reverse().join("");


    // loop through the string to add commas in between
    while (iStart + 3 < lengthOfInteger) {

        // get substring of very 3 digits and add "," at the end
        IntegerConstruction += (reversedInteger.substr(iStart, 3) + ",");

        // increase counter for next 3 digits
        iStart += 3;
    }


    // after adding the commas add the remaining digits 
    IntegerConstruction += reversedInteger.substr(iStart, 3);


    /* now split the constructed string and reverse the array followed by joining to get the formatted number
        ["1" , "2" , "3" , "," ,"4"] - after split
        ["4" , "," , "3" , "2" , "1"] - after reverse
        "4,321" - after join
    */
    numberArray[0] = IntegerConstruction.split("").reverse().join("");

    // return the string as Integer part concatinated with decimal part
    return numberArray.join(".");
}
```